# Match pattern and get parts of string

Tags: c#, regex

I try to match a string in my C# application with regex :

MRT01_60DOOO3-0013577

The rules are :
MRT01_60D can contain mutltiple underscores like MRT_01_02_60D but after the last underscore the string must be :
integer + 'D' or integer + 'M' like :

MRT_01_02_620D or

MRT_01_02_60M or

MRT_03_12D

the last part : OOO3-0013577 length must always be 12 characters and '-' at the 5th position.

After have checked the match of the string, I would like to get 4 parts :

'MRT01'

'60D'

'OOO3-0013'

'577'

Could you help me to find the regex ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Eric.

Comment: Does the string always start with "MRT"? What do you have so far?

Comment: What is the rule that instructs you to break `'OOO3-0013577'` into `'OOO3-0013'` and `'577'`?

Comment: Andrew : the string doesn't always start with "MRT" : this first part is delimited at its end by the last undescore.
Cary : those parts have fixed length : 9 for the 1rst and 3 for the second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(.*)_(\d*[DM])(.{4}-.{4})(.{3})
```

- `(.*)` finds the MRT part (basically any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`)
- `_` an underscore before the D or M part
- `(\d*[DM])` finds any number (`*`) of digits digits (`\d`) ending with D or M (`[DM]`)
- `((.{4}-.{4}))` finds 4 (`{4}`) arbitrary characters (`.`) with a hyphen in the middle and another 4 characters
- `(.{3})` finds 3 characters at the end

Check it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B2kt4u/2)

All items you want to find are put in groups (`()`), so check out group 1 to 4 of the match.

Comment: Thomas : thanks for your answer, as I said to Pavel : the first part doesn't always start with MRT and it may contain multiple underscores like : MRT_01_02_620D or MRT_01_02_60M or AKTT_03_12D

Comment: @eric.bryan: updated. You should specify better next time or give more examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas : your solution perfectly suits my needs.
Thanks a lot to Pavel too for his answer.

Answer (score -1):

For these 2 strings:

```
MRT01_60DOOO3-0013577
MRT_01_60MOOO3-0013577
```

The regex `(MRT.*?\d{2}).*(\d{2}D|\d{2}M)(.{4}-.{4})(.{3})` will match the following:

```
group 1     MRT01
group 2     60D
group 3     OOO3-0013
group 4     577

group 1     MRT_01
group 2     60M
group 3     OOO3-0013
group 4     577
```

After capturing and structuring the strings, in your language of choice (`C#`), just use replacements for characters you don't want like `_`

Comment: Pavel : thanks for your answer, the first part doesn't always start with MRT and it may contain multiple underscores like :
MRT_01_02_620D or
MRT_01_02_60M or
AKTT_03_12D